# Git commands failing HttpRequestException

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am running Git version 2.12.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 running against Microsoft Team Foundation Cloud Service.  No matter what Git command I run I keep getting this same error.  I have even opened my Firewall entirely to see if that was causing it but to no avail.  I have tried Clone, Push, & Pull and they all return this error.

```
git clone https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_git/myProject
Cloning into 'myProject'...
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.

Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at Microsoft.Alm.Git.Trace.Microsoft.Alm.Git.ITrace.Flush()
   at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.Die(String message)
   at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.Die(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: What's your config of `git config --list`? And can you clone/push/pull successfully by VS?

Comment: If this is recent, then it's not unlikely it could be a TLS issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant push git, visual studio. Git failed with a fatal error. fatal: HttpRequestException encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956927/cant-push-git-visual-studio-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-fatal-httprequeste)

Answer (score 7):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/481) on the Git Credential Manager issue tracker and my own experience this morning, a *HttpRequestException* error with an exception of *System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file* with a repository that was previously working is likely due to the repository host rolling out TLS 1.2 as a requirement and you using a version of the Git Credential Manager before 1.14.0 (included with Git for Windows v2.16.2).

To solve, update to Git for Windows v2.16.2 or newer.

To address iagowp directly, if this is a repository hosted on Github, they started to [force TLS 1.2 as of 19:00 UTC on the 22nd of Feb](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/).

Comment: Wait... this is the same issue that I mention in my own answer. Why repeating it?

Comment: When I wrote my answer you did not clearly give the solution as "update git", the version required to solve the problem or details of what the underlying cause of the issue was.

Answer (score 6):

This is a callstack from the [**Git Credential-Manager for Windows**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/): see its [issue 481](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/481).
This is a credential helper which will cache in the Windows Credential Manager store the password associated to an account and remote Git Hosting server URL.

Check the value of `git config credential.helper`

Normal resolution: **upgrade Git** (which embeds GCM).

In the off-chance a year-old file-related error is the by-produc of a GitHub SSL configuration change ([made yesterday](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/)), the [maintainer for Git for Windows just tweeted](https://twitter.com/GitForWindows/status/967054442368589824):

> If you're having trouble connecting to GitHub from Windows today, please make sure to update to the latest version of Git for Windows.
>   GitHub changed their SSL configuration.

---

As a workaround (at least to confirm this is the issue), remove credential.helper from any git config setting file. See `git config -l --show-origin` to list all of them.

Once removed, any clone, if it needs authentication, should prompt you for credentials. But at least, it would not fail.

Check also if the version of the GCM (Git Credential Manager -- for Windows) is the last one or not.

For that, check what Git version you are using.
Check where is your Git program installed: type in CMD session.

```
where git
```

Once you know where Git is installed, you can get to the GCM version embedded in Git:

```
C:\path\To\git
"./mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe" version
Git Credential Manager for Windows version 1.14.0
```

Comment: How to check GCM version?

Comment: @iagowp I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: simplify your answer, to "just update git and you will be ok"