# Can't push git, visual studio. Git failed with a fatal error. fatal: HttpRequestException encountered

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Here is my error on visual studio.
I can't figure out if there is a config to fix this.
Additionally I am restricted from installing git command line tools.

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git failed with a > fatal error. could not read Username for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997966/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-could-not-read-username-for)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that issue.  Daedalon is correct; GitHub's removal of pre-TLS 1.2 have caused this issue.

Comment: I'd recommend changing the accepted answer to Lachezar's answer, for reasons mentioned in Suamere's comment on the currently(3/2/18) accepted answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Cause:** [GitHub updated their security requirements on the server side](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/). They no longer support TLS 1.0 and 1.1, only 1.2. Older Git Credential Manager for Windows versions used 1.0.

**Solution:** Update [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/). Version 2.14.3 and newer include an up-to-date Git Credential Manager for Windows.

Alternatively you can update only the [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0) itself. It supports TLS 1.2 from version 1.14.0 onwards.

Comment: This is great info, but since you should update VS anyway, Lachezar's answer worked better for me.  Updaing VS did indeed solve all of the issues you talked about, without having to finagle with my system in manual ways.

Comment: VS Update did it for me

Comment: @daedalon I have installed VS enterprise 2017 today which is showing up to date. But still while trying to clone a VSTS git repo, I am getting "Git fatal error. HttpRequestException. Cannot spawn..". Can you please give suggestion for this?

Comment: Hi @RohitGarg, sounds like that could be a different error.  If your error message is identical to the one in the original question, double-check that you have the latest version of VS. If you do, you may consider updating Git for Windows or Git Credential Manager separately.

Comment: For me, it got fixed by copying the two dll files I.e. libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from <VS_INSTALL>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\" folder to the "<VS_INSTALL>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core\" folder

Answer (score 32):

Simply update your Visual Studio to the latest version and this should be fixed. Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you Lachezar. Specifically, VS 2017 version 15.5.7 (release 2/20/18) mentions this fix: 
"We have updated the Git and the Git Credential Manager components"

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried this answer first, but had to update Git for Windows before it worked again.

Comment: I have v15.7.6 and still have this issue.  And I updated Git for Windows and Credential Manager too.  Still same error as OP.

Comment: thanks for a tip! worked for me. Also there was a pending update of Windows, after which I updated Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

Git Credential Manager for Windows **v1.17.1** fixes the issue on BitBucket.  Note the one comment:

> Bug Fixes:
>
> ```
> Fixes a bug related to Bitbucket authentication (thanks to @Foda for contributing the fixes).
> ```

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases

Answer (score 2):

This is because Github disabled TLS v1.0 and v1.1,you can read the notice on Github Engineering, here is the link [Weak cryptographic standards removal notice](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/).

From the linked page:

> Last year we announced the deprecation of several weak cryptographic standards. Then we provided a status update toward the end of last year outlining some changes we’d made to make the transition easier for clients. We quickly approached the February 1, 2018 cutoff date we mentioned in previous posts and, as a result, pushed back our schedule by one week.

...

> Visual Studio ships with specific versions of Git for Windows and the Git Credential Manager for Windows (GCM). Microsoft has updated the latest versions of Visual Studio 2017 to work with  TLSv1.2  Git servers. We advise users of Visual Studio to upgrade to the latest release by clicking on the in-product notification flag or by checking for an update directly from the IDE. Microsoft has provided additional guidance on the [Visual Studio developer community support forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have proper configuration. It might be possible if all are okay, there is a wrong email.
Inside Team explorer check Global Settings for email.

Comment: Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Username for 'https://test.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled

Answer (score 1):

In my case, updating git and copying the bin directory cannot fix the error. My solution is checking your git config. 
First, open git bash.
Second, check git config. `git config -l`
The http.proxy and https.proxy would make you cannot update the project successfully. And if you use vpn, and make the 1080 port open, that would make the upload not so smoothly.(Only the case that your vpn is slow)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the above didn't work since my google email address for bitbucket had 2 factor authentication. So I had to create a bitbucket app token and in the origin https url I had to put the token that was generated like so https://username:appToken@bitbucket.org/repo/test.git

Answer (score 1):

You code written above is right, but if you can pull and can't push, but you can push just in console and not in VS, and you are behind a corporate proxy, then you might try another approach. It may work for you:

1. Create GitHub token: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line#creating-a-token
2. In the `.gitconfig` file write:

   ```
   [credential] 
   authority = *the-token*"
   ```
3. Search for the file `.gitconfig`  by command: `git config --list --show-origin`

Answer (score 0):

[Git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) on windows was giving trouble even after typing in the password in the pop up window.
I tried with `Git Gui` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

open your project folder path, right-click on the folder, select Git Bash, in that type the command

git config --global http.sslVerify false

[git command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Kik.png)

Then try to Sync, fetch and pull, it will work

Comment: This is not a viable solution, you are setting `http.sslVerify` globally to false which compromises security.