# Why do I get a "Fatal: Http Request Exception encountered" even upon doing a successful push?

Tags: git

Why does the Fatal Http Request Exception  encountered message occur even after having a successful git push as shown below

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\pick2get\pic2get_>git push -u origin master
Fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
Username for 'https://github.com': CharlesNjau
Password for 'https://CharlesNjau@github.com':
Counting objects: 219, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (209/209), done.
Writing objects: 38% (84/219), 984.00 KiB | 24.00 KiB/s
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't push git, visual studio. Git failed with a fatal error. fatal: HttpRequestException encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956927/cant-push-git-visual-studio-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-fatal-httprequest)

Comment: Not a duplicate question I pushed successfully and this still occurred and i wanted to know why

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is caused by a mismatch of TLS: depending on your configuration you may want to update your account manager or check visual studio extensions updates.

[Have a look here](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-solve-the-github-error-fatal-httprequestexception-encountered/)

Comment: Thanks after following the link recommended the problem was solved

Comment: Worked for me too. @Charles can you accept that as a correct answer?