# HTTPS request exception on git push to GitHub

Tags: github, repo, git-for-windows

I've been trying to push a personal site of mine to GitHub but anytime I get to `git push -u origin main` an error occurs.

I usually see:

> fatal: HTTPS request exception encountered, an error occurs while sending the request.

What can I do?

I repeated the process again and again. I even tried removing the repository and adding it back.

Comment: Which version of git are you using, and from where (IDE, Terminal, etc.) are you running your git commands? Is this the complete error message? You can also have a look at these questions: [Why do I get a "Fatal: Http Request Exception encountered" even upon doing a successful push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967720/why-do-i-get-a-fatal-http-request-exception-encountered-even-upon-doing-a-suc), [Git commands failing HttpRequestException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057820/git-commands-failing-httprequestexception).